# How to avoid many if/else conditions in the method?

Tags: java

I'm in doubts am on right way for one of my methods. This one is a compositor of `URI` I'm using for my `http requests`. It just takes data from a separate static class with final `Strings`, merges them together and includes received from the server token where necessary. It happened all `URIs` are with token and the only one, authentication, without it. What I've done:

```
private URI urlComposer(String apiUri, String token) { 
        URI uri = null;
        try {

            if(apiUri.equals("POST_AUTH_URL")) {
                uri = URIUtils.createURI(null, MyConfig.WEB_SERVER, -1, apiUri, null, null);
                return uri; 
            }

            String tmp = apiUri.toString();
            String[] array = tmp.split("<token>");
            tmp = array[0] + auth.getToken() + array[1];

            uri = URIUtils.createURI(null, MyConfig.WEB_SERVER, -1, tmp, null, null);

            if (MyConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("Dev", "Constructed url " + uri);
            return uri; 
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            if (MyConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("Dev", "urlComposer was unable to construct a URL"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Trying to look in the future I don't like the idea to generate more if/else statements if I would have more special cases like this `POST_AUTH_URL`. One one hand I want the only one method to be called to construct a URI, on the other I don't want these `ifs`. What shall I do?

Comment: your second call to URIUtis.createURI always overwrites uri, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If you always set URIs, only different ones, you can use a map:

```
uriMap.put("POST_AUTH_URL", URIUtils.createURI(null, MyConfig.WEB_SERVER, -1, apiUri, null, null));
```

You can access this map later:

```
uri = uriMap.get(apiUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically create an enum URI_TYPE with method createURI (it is difficult to derive the actual parameters from the provided code snippet). This way you'd simply invoke this method on a specific enum value, which would have its own specific implementation.

Pls refer [this](http://techpolesen.blogspot.com/2007/07/switch-considered-harmful-advanced.html) and [this](http://battlingjava.blogspot.com/2007/11/using-enums-in-java.html) for more information. Hope it helps.